# Caption text field non editable in specific word document

Tags: microsoft-word-2016, caption

I didn't find a community which seemed more suited to present this problem to.

I am using MS Word 2016 on Windows 10.

I've been writing a document for a while now, but today, out of the blue, when I tried to insert a caption to a figure, the **Caption** text field was *locked*, *non-editable*, I don't know what else to call it.

This is a document I've been writing on for months, and this had never happened before. I made a copy in a different folder, in a different partition, just to see if there were some permissions or configuration-related issues, which sounds far fetched but I've really run out of ideas here.

The problem occurs in this document and any copy of it. Other word documents don't present the problem.

[image]

Any thoughts?

EDIT

Well, I found a workaround, or more like I found the actual problem, not how to solve it, though.

It's not that I can't write in it, **it's that I can't see what I'm writing**, because when I type something it doesn't show me what I'm typing but then I hit OK, and the caption IS indeed inserted in the document.

Exactly what is described [here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/bug-word-insert-caption-ui-issue/4d559e37-e1a3-4f10-bb0b-d0b6ef340534), although no solution either.

There are comments relating this to screen resolution issues, but mine doesn't seem to be that case, since my problem only occurs on this specific document (and copies of it) but not in others.

Thanks

Comment: I will post something explaining it soon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am just explaining and extending on what the OP has found and possibly showing how he/she can solve the problem.

Normally, when inserting a caption, this is what happens:
[image: IMG:]

That's because the Caption style text alignment is set on the left. If the alignment is set on the right, then when entering the caption, you will not see the cursor, and it will appear as if you are not entering anything although you are. When you click OK, the cation appears on the right.

[image: IMG:]

What you need to do is to modify the Caption style. Display your styles for the ribbon, right-click on Caption, then click on Modify.

[image: IMG:]

Select the left alignment, then click OK. You will again be able to see what you are typing when entering a caption.

[image: IMG:]

Comment: I verified that is indeed the case, only it also happens when the format is set to *centered*, not just *right*. so this is definitely a bug, right? I mean, I shouldn't have to change the format (which I had configured purposefully) just so I can see what I'm typing in the Caption dialog, right?

Comment: @Scaramouche There are times when it happens even when centered. But in my case, it didn't that's why I only posted the example with right alignment.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem and I had solved that.

1. Place your cursor in the place caption will be created

[image: Check this Image 1]

2. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> to show Styles dialog.

[image: Check this Image 2]

3. Click "Caption" and click modify

[image: Check this Image 3]

4. Make sure the Style is "Normal" and that alignment is "left" and then click "OK"

[image: Check this Image 4]

5. Now you can insert the caption and can edit the text in the caption box.

[image: Check this Image 5]

Hope this will help.